# How to do a batch search in Redis?

Tags: python, redis, vector-database, vector-search

I use Redis as a vector database. I want to make multiple search queries, but I can't find how to do it in documentation. Now it looks like:

```
client = redis.Redis(host="localhost", port=6379, decode_responses=True)
# insert data

# search
query = (
    Query("*=>[KNN 2 @vector $vec as score]")
     .sort_by("score")
     .return_fields("id", "score")
     .paging(0, 2)
     .dialect(2)
)

query_params = {
    "vec": np.random.rand(VECTOR_DIMENSIONS).astype(np.float32).tobytes()
}
r.ft(INDEX_NAME).search(query, query_params).docs
```

This example I take from redis-py documentation: [documentation](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/search_vector_similarity_examples.html).

But it is only for one query per search. I need something like that:

```
query_params = {
    "vec": [np.random.rand(VECTOR_DIMENSIONS).astype(np.float32).tobytes(),
np.random.rand(VECTOR_DIMENSIONS).astype(np.float32).tobytes()]
}
r.ft(INDEX_NAME).search(query, query_params).docs
```

Is it possible?